# XenServer and Quiesced snapshots

Tags: xenserver, snapshot, quiesce

At work we use XenServer to administrate all the VM's. Now I wrote a script which enables Linux machines quiesced support. The script works absolutely fine. It activates if someone triggers a quiesced snapshot. Now here's the big question: Do the protection policies support creating quiesced snapshots ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out what I had to do:

I had to add some python code to xcp-storage-managers/drivers/vmpr to check if the VM supports quiesce if it does then it should create a quiesce snapshot else it should do a normal snapshot.

Comment: Can you please post the code or make a github gist?

Comment: @portforwardpodcast sorry, first I have to clear it with my boss

Comment: Great. This would be a good addition to the world!!